# Explain some code

Tags: jquery

What is happening in below jQuery code ?

```
$("#myDiv").val($(".cssValue").sortable('serialize',{expression: 'textExp[#]'}));
```

I understand its enabling sortable on a css value within a div, I'm open to correction on this.

I'm confused about this section:

```
'serialize',{expression: 'textExp[#]'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand its enabling sortable on a css value within a div, I'm open to correction on this.

`.sortable('serialize',{expression: 'textExp[#]'})` is actually the jQuery UI syntax for invoking a method on a previously instantiated jQuery UI widget.  That is to say, this line isn't actually making `.cssValue` sortable - that was done at a previous point in time. This command simply serializes the element.

Here's a full run down:

```
// select an element with id='myDiv'
$("#myDiv")
    // note: .val() is used for setting the value of form fields, so this doesn't
    // seem to make a lot of sense, given that #myDiv is presumably a div
    .val(
        // select an element with class='cssValue'
        $(".cssValue")
            // call the serialize method on this jQuery UI sortable element
            // this will return a serialization of .cssValue - check out
            // the methods tab here http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
            .sortable('serialize', { expression: 'textExp[#]'})
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-serialize

Signature:
.sortable( "serialize" , [options] )
Serializes the sortable's item id's into a form/ajax submittable string. Calling this method produces a hash that can be appended to any url to easily submit a new item order back to the server.

It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format 'setname_number', and it spits out a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".

You can also give in a option hash as second argument to custom define how the function works. The possible options are: 'key' (replaces part1[] with whatever you want), 'attribute' (test another attribute than 'id') and 'expression' (use your own regexp).

If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form: "set_number" For example, a 3 element list with id attributes foo_1, foo_5, foo_2 will serialize to foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2. You can use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and number. For example foo=1 or foo-1 or foo_1 all serialize to foo[]=1.

Answer (score 0):

It's setting the value of the element with the id `myDiv` to be sortable. (`sortable` is a jQuery plugin, [see this page](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable).)